# Replicating black and white hatching pattern fills in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, cartography, visualisation, filling

I am looking to replicate black & white maps in QGIS, using hatching patterns and greyscales to indicate different categories of a continuous variable (example below).

It is possible/straightforward to do so in QGIS? At first sight I only see color gradients and symbol fills.

[image: example]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is very straightforward - but you won't get a set of automatic styles for each level. Under 'style', in 'symbol layer type', select a 'line pattern fill':

[image: Crosshatch fill]

Add more symbol layers (the green + button in the image above) with line layers at different angles to get crosshatching:

[image]

To replicate the map you showed as an example, you'll want to do a 'graduated' symbol type instead of 'single symbol', and do a custom fill for each graduated level.

Answer (score 4):

This workaround might work for you:

1. classify with color ramp "Greys"
2. In the style tab, click on the colored symbol
3. Change fill style from solid to Dense 1
4. Proceed with the following symbols until Dense 7

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the style section of the layer properties choose categorized and Symbol:"change". In the lower left corner there is a little plus where you can add the pattern.

You can also classify your layer in the symbology section and edit the style of the different categories by hand. If you need this for multiple layers you can save the style and load it in the new layer. I dont think there are grayscales in your map, the over 75% category is just a very dense hatching pattern.