# Using pattern styled polygons in Tilemill

Tags: tilemill, mapnik, cartocss

I'm just learning CartoCSS with Tilemill.

I've got a really simple requirement for styling a polygon but cannot find any hint nowhere.

What is the code for styling simple polygon fills?

For example, like can be seen here:

[Black/white hatching pattern](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94326/black-white-hatching-pattern-fills-in-qgis)

Answer (score 2):

> You can easily fill areas with textures and patterns by bringing in
> external images. You might create the patterns yourself in image
> editing software such as GIMP or Inkscape, or find ready-made images
> from resource websites such as Subtle Patterns or Free Seamless
> Textures.

Taken from the [TileMill Documentation](https://tilemill-project.github.io/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-polygons/) where you can find an easy example.