# Apply Line Pattern Fill to LineStrings?

Tags: qgis, symbology, line, fill

I am trying to print out a network map using black/white hatching patterns, similar to [Black/white hatching pattern fills in QGis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94326/black-white-hatching-pattern-fills-in-qgis) but for Lines. Is there some trick I can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to create a hatched line with a border you need to layer 3 linestyles (you can add them with the green "+" button). Your first (bottom) layer must be a simple black continuous line, set to a certain width (let's say 5).[image]

If your lines have bends in them, be sure to set the connection-style to round (apologies, I do not know the correct English terms).

Your second layer needs to be a white continuous line that is placed on top of the black line to create the illusion of a black bordered line. This second layer needs to be a little narrower than the black one (4,25 for example).[image]

Your third and top layer is the hatched pattern. For this you need to pick a simple vertical line symbol and give it an angle and also make sure the width reaches the "borders". 
[image]
With this grouped line symbol you can change the line width of the whole thing, no need to change each layer individually.

Comment: thanks, I came up with something similar, but did not manage to set the rotation (relative to direction of the line segment) properly - absolute rotation does not work well when the line segment is in the same direction

Answer (score 7):

to achieve this result:

[image]

- Open `layer properties` (right click on layer > properties)
- Go to the tab `Symbology`

And set properties to folowing:

[image]